# Enabling CSRF Protection for Mailchimp Subscribe plugin and other forms

Tags: form, security, csrf, plugin-amforms, plugin-mailchimpsubscribe

I'm using the [MailChimp Subscribe for Craft](https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft) plugin to embed several subscription forms on a website I'm building.

The following code appears via my master `_layout.html` file:

```
<form action="" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mailchimpSubscribe/list/Subscribe">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="successfully-subscribed">

    {# MailChimp List ID #}
    <input type="hidden" name="lid" value="XXXXXXXXXX">

    {% if mailchimpSubscribe is defined %}
        {% if (not mailchimpSubscribe.success) and (mailchimpSubscribe.errorCode!='1000') %}
            <p>An error occured. Please try again.</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    <div class="field-line">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="mcvars[NAME]" value="{% if (mailchimpSubscribe is defined) and (not mailchimpSubscribe.success) %}{{ mailchimpSubscribe.values.vars.NAME }}{% endif %}" required>
    </div>

    <div class="field-line">
        <label{% if (mailchimpSubscribe is defined) and (mailchimpSubscribe.errorCode=='1000') %} class="error"{% endif %}>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" value="{% if (mailchimpSubscribe is defined) and (not mailchimpSubscribe.success) %}{{ mailchimpSubscribe.values.email }}{% endif %}" required>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="" value="Go!">

</form>
```

When I hit go, I get the following Bad Request error:

[image: Bad Request]

I've temporarily fixed the error via `general.php` by disabling CSRF Protection (not recommended).

How do I implement CSRF Protection on this form? I've followed [this article](https://craftcms.com/support/csrf-protection), but replacing the name and value fields will surely disable the plugin's functionality?

Should I also implement the method shown [here](https://craftcms.com/support/csrf-protection) for other forms like [Am Forms](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms)?

**Update:**
There's a pull request on the [plugin git page](https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft/pull/43) regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable CSRF protection in your config again and add `{{ getCsrfInput() }}` right after the `<form>` opening tag on *all* forms on your site, regardless if they are amforms or mailchimp subscribe.  I can verify that it won't interfere with the mailchimp plugin as I am currently (and just recently) installed it on a project I'm working on and it works fine.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I can confirm it's working perfectly.